# How to install ubuntu on free dos

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-to-install-ubuntu)

I am buying a samsung rv 509 laptop which come with dos pre installed. I want to install Ubuntu. I am new to Linux and am baiscally a home user. Please guide me (preferably step by step) how to install it. Currently I have a XP desktop with no provision for CD burning but there is a provision for USB drive.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu - the above link has all the information you need to install from USB.  Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to the Ubuntu download page:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

Start downloading your preferred version of Ubuntu (the default should be fine). After a couple of hours (depending on your internet connection), look down to section 2. Check "USB stick" and "Windows", and click "Show me how". Follow those instructions to make a Ubuntu install USB stick.

Once your USB stick is ready, plug it into your new laptop. Once you boot from that install USB stick, the instructions on on screen will take you through it step by step.